# Phrase or expression for "sending a message to the wrong recipient" in chat

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a short phrase or expression for sending a message in the wrong place, when chatting online?

When (text) chatting online, there can be times when someone inadvertently sends something that was not meant to be sent there. This could include sending a message to the wrong channel or person, or typing something that was meant to be input elsewhere (such as a password or search engine query).

Is there a short word or expression for performing such an action or describing such a situation?

I'm not looking for *mistype* or *typo*; I'm looking for something that emphasizes that it's an incorrect location more.

For example, one might say,

> Whenever I log into my email I'm afraid that I will [...], as I always have a chat window open.

or

> Because I [...], my friend discovered that we were planning a surprise party to celebrate his new job.

Comment: Depending on content and addressee, you might call it "a disastrous click"

Comment: Well, there's always [butt dial](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2019/10/25/butt-dial-heard-round-world/).

Answer (score 3):

This can be called a ***mistext***

From [Slangit](https://slangit.com/meaning/mistext):

> A text sent to the wrong person
>   A mistext is an accidental text that is sent to the wrong recipient. It usually is sent to the person that the text was about, which makes the error even more awkward.
>
> Mistexts are usually the product of a person who is rushed and carrying on conversations with other people at the same time. They result in a textastrophe or textmergency that requires further explanation from the sender/perpetrator.
>
> Example
>   *"I got a mistext from Jess the other day and she was throwing major shade at me."*

Comment: [Also hyphenated as mis-text](https://textplus.com/blog/2017/5/23/how-to-recover-from-4-common-mis-texts).

Answer (score 1):

**Misdirected text** is the term I'm seeing online. For example [an article by CNET on a patent by Apple entitled:](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-aims-to-prevent-misdirected-text-messages/)

> *Apple aims to prevent misdirected text messages*

[An article on boredom therapy:](https://boredomtherapy.com/wrong-number-texts/?bdk=a*undefined&ch=bt)

> Everyone occasionally texts a wrong number accidentally. The recipient of these **misdirected texts** has a few options: they can politely point out the mistake, they can ignore it, or… they can hilariously prank the poor person on the other end of the line!

Unlike the notion of a [butt dial](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/butt-dial) which means you dialed your phone accidentally, the misdirected text requires actual user error.

That said, I've heard people try to connect the phrase *butt text* or even using butt dial for when a string of characters you didn't intend to send goes out.

People also call this an **accidental text** and if done on purpose a [*fake accidental text*](https://melmagazine.com/en-us/story/the-case-of-the-fake-accidental-text).

Answer (score 0):

Mistell - **Noun**. mistell (plural mistells) A message sent to the incorrect recipient in an instant messaging program or online game.

Comment: What's the source of this definition?

Comment: definitions.net, freedictionary.org, yourdictionary.org, collinsdictionary.com, etc. etc.

Comment: If you could you add the reference to the text of the answer that would be preferred, as comments are ephemeral in nature.

Answer (score 0):

"To go astray" is the correct expression in my opinion.
Eg most of the letters went astray or were not delivered.